# Javascript Code not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have this code which truncate the text to a number of characters, then shows when you click the "More" and toggle back when you click the "Less".
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
//]]>
$j(window).load(function() {
    var showChar = 600;  // The default length of characters to be shown
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "More >>";
    var lesstext = "Less <<";       

    $j('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $j(this).html();   
        if(content.length > showChar) {  
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);     
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';   
            $j(this).html(html);
        }    
    });

    $j(".morelink").click(function() {
        if($j(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $j(this).removeClass("less");
            $j(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $j(this).addClass("less");
            $j(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $j(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $j(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

It is working fine on Chrome and Opera but not in Firefox. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: check what is the error in your firefox console.

Comment: it is not related to the script above. @AnkitKathiriya

Comment: Your code is working on chrom but not working on firefox there for some browser issue please check firefox console if any error is come or not?

Comment: if any error come then please tell

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya this is on the console http://snag.gy/64H5T.jpg

Comment: in my answer it works perfectly in firefox also.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$j(".more").on('click','.morelink',function(){
        if($j(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $j(this).removeClass("less");
            $j(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $j(this).addClass("less");
            $j(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $j(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $j(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
```

& use document ready statement(`$(function(){})`), `.load()` is a ajax function

Comment: I think the error is on the onload... it seems that the code for truncating the text is not working. @madalinivascu

Answer (score 0):

This Demo is work perfectly.

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
  var showChar = 600; // The default length of characters to be shown
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "More >>";
  var lesstext = "Less <<";

  $j('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $j(this).html();
    if (content.length > showChar) {
      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
      $j(this).html(html);
    }
  });

  $j(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($j(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $j(this).removeClass("less");
      $j(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $j(this).addClass("less");
      $j(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $j(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $j(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="more">sdgagafgadfgafdgafdgafgadfghshdghdghdfhdfjshlkjabgaglakjgfaljgLJGNlkgfbdfagnfldkgalkjfgalkgjaflkghalkfgjhakldfgsfgj;adsfkgjs;dfklj;dlgkjsdfgkjsdf;gkjsfd;kgsjh'lkjglhkd'sfhkld'hklds'ghkl';glkh'sdlgkh'slgkh'slkhs'lhks'hkls'lkhs'klhs'hkl'shklfjghlakghalfjghalkgjf;bvklb;kjaajgpijg;aflkdjg;akflgj;akfgj;akfljg;akfgja;lfkgja;lfkgadfadfafadfafaafe;gjegjlfkgjs;k;kgsl;kfdjg;skdfjg;lskjfg;lksfjg;slkfjg;slfdgsf;kgjwoirwprlkfgslkrglkhsfdlkgjhglkruhtsgfkjlhakjdshgjkhasfguhreihkghlzkjfdghkugeirgeghdkjhgskjdfgksrhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgkgjwoirwprlkfgslkrglkhsfdlkgjhglkruhtsgfkjlhakjdshgjkhasfguhreihkghlzkjfdghkugeirgeghdkjhgskjdfgksrhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgkgjwoirwprlkfgslkrglkhsfdlkgjhglkruhtsgfkjlhakjdshgjkhasfguhreihkghlzkjfdghkugeirgeghdkjhgskjdfgksrhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgkgjwoirwprlkfgslkrglkhsfdlkgjhglkruhtsgfkjlhakjdshgjkhasfguhreihkghlzkjfdghkugeirgeghdkjhgskjdfgksrhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgkgjwoirwprlkfgslkrglkhsfdlkgjhglkruhtsgfkjlhakjdshgjkhasfguhreihkghlzkjfdghkugeirgeghdkjhgskjdfgksrhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgkgjwoirwprlkfgslkrglkhsfdlkgjhglkruhtsgfkjlhakjdshgjkhasfguhreihkghlzkjfdghkugeirgeghdkjhgskjdfgksrhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgkgjwoirwprlkfgslkrglkhsfdlkgjhglkruhtsgfkjlhakjdshgjkhasfguhreihkghlzkjfdghkugeirgeghdkjhgskjdfgksrhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhgushfogisuhfdgisuhfgishgiushgiushgiushgisuhgiureheihiegsfjghdkhgisurhg</span>
```

Comment: I means that my code is ok... maybe the conflict is within the other JS codes,,, I will work on that.